# Keep user signed in with "Sign in with Google" WITHOUT automatic sign in

Tags: javascript, node.js, authentication, google-signin, google-api-nodejs-client

How do I prevent users from being signed out after only 1 hour when using google sign in?
automatic sign in is not a solution because it does not work with users with multiple google accounts, forcing the user to choose their account each time the token expires.

To be clear, I am using "Sign in with Google" as documented here
https://developers.google.com/identity/gsi/web/guides/overview

My code as it stands, with automatic sign in still here until it can be gotten rid of.

```
window.onload = function () {
    google.accounts.id.initialize({
      client_id: "1234567890.apps.googleusercontent.com",
      auto_select: true,
      state_cookie_domain: "http://localhost:8080",
      callback: handleCredentialResponse
    });
    google.accounts.id.renderButton(
      document.getElementById("buttonDiv"),
      { theme: "outline", size: "large" }  // customization attributes
    );
   }
```

Comment: How do I bump a question that isnt getting answered?